# How to prevent user from deleting/editing or adding records on subform in MS ACCESS 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

[image: This is the form]

As you can see on the image above, I have a form with subform attached inside it. What I want is to prevent user from directly Adding or Deleting and even Editing records or items inside the subform and only allowed the text fields and buttons to do the Adding Deleting and Editing.

Note: I have no knowledge in VBA.

Comment: Goto Subform properties (In design mode) => Data tab => Allow Additions=No, Allow Deletions=No, Allow Edits=No

Comment: This makes no sense. You have no button to allow edits, and - further - why add a record, if the user cannot edit it?

Comment: So the main form and subform show same data and this is emulating the intrinsic Split form. The datasheet portion of Split form can be set to ReadOnly. Otherwise, do what Santosh suggested. Is the main form bound? BTW, `discreption` is a misspelling.

Comment: @Gustav I did not create a edit button simply because I can use the find records using next and previous button and simply change whatever details that I want to change in the text box and click save. I already tried that and it works. My only concern here is to lock the subform to prevent user to make changes directly to the subform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, when clicking either of these buttons, you could:

1. set *AllowAdditions* and -*Deletions*, respectively, to *True*
2. *add/delete* the record
3. set *AllowAdditions* or -*Deletions* to *False*

To open the form for *data entry only* (not showing existing records), set the form's *DataEntry* property to: *Yes* (True).

Comment: Thank you for the response, I already tried that but the problem is, it will take effect to the whole form. I only want to lock the sub form. What I mean by that is, I don't want any of those actions done into the subform.

Comment: It won't matter. Either operation should take no more than a split second.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how can I keep my text box blank every time I open my form? As you can see on the image above, the record show's in the textbox even if I didn't call it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow … you want to be able to edit a textbox/record, but not show the record? If so, how would the user know which record is edited?

Comment: Sorry if I confused you, this should be in another topic but I just tried to bring it up here hoping that you can help me out. What I'm asking is, is there anyway that I can keep my text box blank every time I open up my form? because usually when your input a record in your table using a form that record which your entered will always appear on the text boxes when you or everytime you display that form.

Comment: Sounds like a form in data entry mode. See edited answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

For any users trying to lock addition/deletion of records in a subform permanently (but still allow edits):

- Go to Design View of main form
- Select subform and right-click
- Select "Subform in New Window" from drop down menu
- Navigate to the Data tab in the subform's property sheet
- Change Allow Deletions/Allow Additions properties to "No"